# $\frac{\partial Ψ}{\partial x}(x,y)=\frac{\partial Φ}{\partial y}(x,y)$ for all $(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

Give a piar functions $Φ:\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R $ and $Ψ: \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$, it is often useful to known that there exists some contiunously differentiable function $f:\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$ such that $\partial f/\partial x(x,y)=Φ(x,y)$ and $\partial f/\partial y(x,y)=Ψ(x,y)$ for all $(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2$

Such a function $f$ is called a potential function for the pair of functions $(Φ,Ψ)$

Show that there is a potential function for the pair of continuously differentiable functions $Φ:\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R $ and $Ψ: \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$ then

$\frac{\partial Ψ}{\partial x}(x,y)=\frac{\partial Φ}{\partial y}(x,y)$ for all $(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2$

Sorry for not writing any idea. I dont want to write Wrong things. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$$
\frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}
$$

What is $\partial_y\Phi$?

Comment: $\frac{\partial Φ}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$

Comment: After there, how will be continue to solve?

Comment: Exactly.  And since the derivatives are continuous, those mixed partials of $f$ are equal to each other.

Comment: Okay, since the derivatives are continuous, they are equal. But how do we show the effect of countinity to these mixed partials of $f$ be equal? Is this a theorem?

Comment: Hopefully, you understand my question..:)

Comment: Yes - that is a theorem that should be in your book (or that you have proved in class).

Comment: I dont know the theorem, but I am searching this. I Will learn its proof. Thank you :))